# Find libraries in Windows(MSVC) with CMake

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, cmake

im having an issue trying to link libraries in MSVC. I have some  external dependencies i have compiled for release and debug and set them in different folder (${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/External/Debug/lib and ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/External/Release/lib). I have written some FindFoo.cmake modules which have as a HINT for the find_library command a ${EXTERNAL_LIB_DIR} which is set depending on the ${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}.

This work perfects on Linux but fails in Windows (it always set the EXTERNAL_LIB_DIR path to the Debug path) and fails to link because of _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL.

Here is an example of the FindFoo.cmake I'm using.

```
FIND_PATH(SOIL_INCLUDE_DIR                                                                                    
NAMES SOIL/SOIL.h                                                                                         
PATHS                                                                                                     
${EXTERNAL_DIR}/soil/inc                                                                                  
NO_DEFAULT_PATH                                                                                           
)                                                                                                         


find_library(                                                                                                 
SOIL_LIBRARY                                                                                              
    NAMES SOIL soil soil_debug                                                                            
PATHS                                                                                                     
    ${EXTERNAL_LIB_DIR}                                                                                   
    NO_DEFAULT_PATH                                                                                       
)                                                                                                         


INCLUDE(FindPackageHandleStandardArgs)                                                                        

FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS(SOIL DEFAULT_MSG SOIL_LIBRARY S 
SOIL_INCLUDE_DIR)                             


if (${SOIL_FOUND})                                                                                            
SET(SOIL_INCLUDE_DIRS ${SOIL_INCLUDE_DIR})                                                                
SET(SOIL_LIBRARIES    ${SOIL_LIBRARY})                                                                    
endif()                                                                                                       


MARK_AS_ADVANCED( SOIL_LIBRARY SOIL_INCLUDE_DIR )
```

And here the creation of EXTERNAL_LIB_DIR
    # Set external libraries

```
set(EXTERNAL_DIR ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/External)                                                              

if (${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE} MATCHES Debug)                                                                        
set(EXTERNAL_LIB_DIR ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/External/lib/Debug)                                            
else()                                                                                                        
set(EXTERNAL_LIB_DIR ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/External/lib/Release)                                          

endif()                                                                                                       
message(STATUS "Using libraries in ${EXTERNAL_LIB_DIR}")
```

How should I modify the FindFoo.cmake of the creation of the EXTERNAL_LIB_DIR variable to make it work with MSVC?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need two different `find_library` calls, one for debug and one for release.

```
find_library(SOIL_LIBRARY_DEBUG NAMES soil_debug
    PATHS ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/External/lib/Debug
    NO_DEFAULT_PATH)
find_library(SOIL_LIBRARY_RELEASE NAMES SOIL soil 
    PATHS ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/External/lib/Release
    NO_DEFAULT_PATH)
set(SOIL_LIBRARIES debug ${SOIL_LIBRARY_DEBUG} optimized ${SOIL_LIBRARY_RELEASE})

target_link_libraries(foo ${SOIL_LIBRARIES})
```

Note that this is still not entirely correct, as it does not distinguish all four of the default configurations (Debug, Release, MinSizeRel and RelWithDebInfo) correctly, but it's good enough for most use cases.

In modern CMake, instead of exposing the find results through variables, find scripts typically create imported targets, which in theory offer the same flexibility as [config-file packages](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.10/manual/cmake-packages.7.html#config-file-packages), if you need it. Take a look at the scripts that ship with newer CMake versions to get an idea how this can look like ([`FindZlib.cmake`](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/blob/master/Modules/FindZLIB.cmake) is a good example, as it is rather small).

Never rely on `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` in find scripts, as it [is only supported by single-config generators](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.10/variable/CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE.html) (like Makefiles)!

Comment: Thank you very much, was exactly what I was looking for. I will also have a look to imported targets, since Ive always used CMake through variables.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to elaborate the answer of [ComicSansMS](https://stackoverflow.com/users/577603/comicsansms). He point me into the right direction.

I'm coming here because I was looking for a solution to find the libraries of a [GoogleTest](https://github.com/google/googletest) installation on Linux and MS Windows. First I had a look at the **cmake** module [FindGTest](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.18/module/FindGTest.html) but that's a bit buggy (don't provide correct directories) and also do not provide paths to **gmock** that I also need. So I decided to look for the directories by myself using cmake `find_library()`.

Installing **GoogleTest** is not an issue here. I use its default installation on the `build/` directory and get:

```
# On Linux with build type Debug
tree build/lib/
build/lib/
├── libgmock_maind.a
├── libgmockd.a
├── libgtest_maind.a
└── libgtestd.a

# On Linux with build type Release
tree build/lib/
build/lib/
├── libgmock.a
├── libgmock_main.a
├── libgtest.a
└── libgtest_main.a
```

Note that there is a `d` appended to the library names with **Debug**. The newer installation overwrites the old one.

```
# On MS Windows with build type Debug and Release
build/lib/
├── Debug
│   ├── gmock_maind.lib
│   ├── gmock_maind.pdb
│   ├── gmockd.lib
│   ├── gmockd.pdb
│   ├── gtest_maind.lib
│   ├── gtest_maind.pdb
│   ├── gtestd.lib
│   └── gtestd.pdb
└── Release
    ├── gmock.lib
    ├── gmock_main.lib
    ├── gtest.lib
    └── gtest_main.lib
```

MS Windows does not overwrite an old build type but it has additional subdirectories. For example I want all four libraries `gtest[d]`, `gtest_main[d]`, `gmock[d]` and `gmock_main[d]` to add as libraries for link targets on both operating systems without modification:

```
message("CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_PREFIXES is: ${CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_PREFIXES}")
message("CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES is: ${CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES}")
find_library(GTEST_STATIC_LIBRARY gtest gtestd
             PATHS ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib
             PATH_SUFFIXES Debug Release MinSizeRel RelWithDebInfo
             NO_DEFAULT_PATH)
message("GTEST_STATIC_LIBRARY is: ${GTEST_STATIC_LIBRARY}")

find_library(GMOCK_STATIC_LIBRARY gmock gmockd
             PATHS ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib
             PATH_SUFFIXES Debug Release MinSizeRel RelWithDebInfo
             NO_DEFAULT_PATH)
message("GMOCK_STATIC_LIBRARY is: ${GMOCK_STATIC_LIBRARY}")

find_library(GTEST_MAIN_STATIC_LIBRARY gtest_main gtest_maind
             PATHS ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib
             PATH_SUFFIXES Debug Release MinSizeRel RelWithDebInfo
             NO_DEFAULT_PATH)
message("GTEST_MAIN_STATIC_LIBRARY is: ${GTEST_MAIN_STATIC_LIBRARY}")

find_library(GMOCK_MAIN_STATIC_LIBRARY gmock_main gmock_maind
             PATHS ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib
             PATH_SUFFIXES Debug Release MinSizeRel RelWithDebInfo
             NO_DEFAULT_PATH)
message("GMOCK_MAIN_STATIC_LIBRARY is: ${GMOCK_MAIN_STATIC_LIBRARY}")

link_libraries(${GTEST_STATIC_LIBRARY} ${GMOCK_STATIC_LIBRARY}
               ${GTEST_MAIN_STATIC_LIBRARY} ${GMOCK_MAIN_STATIC_LIBRARY})
```

This order will match only the Release build if both builds are available. If you prefer to match Debug first then just reorder the library names. With PATH_SUFFIXES the find will match all possible build types. As result I get for Release:

```
# On Linux:
~$ rm -rf build/ && cmake -S . -B build -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
--- snip ---
CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_PREFIXES is: lib
CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES is: .so;.a
GTEST_STATIC_LIBRARY is: /home/ingo/develbuild/lib/libgtest.a
GMOCK_STATIC_LIBRARY is: /home/ingo/develbuild/lib/libgtest.a
GTEST_MAIN_STATIC_LIBRARY is: /home/ingo/develbuild/lib/libgtest_main.a
GMOCK_MAIN_STATIC_LIBRARY is: /home/ingo/develbuild/lib/libgmock_main.a

rem On MS Windows:
~>cmake --build build --config Release
--- snip ---
CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_PREFIXES is:
CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES is: .lib
GTEST_STATIC_LIBRARY is: C:/Users/ingo/devel/build/lib/Release/gtest.lib
GMOCK_STATIC_LIBRARY is: C:/Users/ingo/devel/build/lib/Release/gmock.lib
GTEST_MAIN_STATIC_LIBRARY is: C:/Users/ingo/devel/build/lib/Release/gtest_main.lib
GMOCK_MAIN_STATIC_LIBRARY is: C:/Users/ingo/devel/build/lib/Release/gmock_main.lib
```

CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_PREFIXES and MAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES are normaly initialized by **cmake**.